# What are T-SQL Statement Blocks?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, return

While researching something I can across an [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998.aspx) which says:

> Exits unconditionally from a query or procedure. RETURN is immediate
>   and complete and can be used at any point to exit from a procedure,
>   batch, or **statement block**. Statements that follow RETURN are not
>   executed.

The documentation didn't come close to the specific situation I was researching.  After reading it I realized that I didn't understand the Return statement, and (more specifically) the definition of "**statement blocks**" as well as I thought.  So...

What exactly is a t-sql "statement block"?  Are they defined by `Begin ... End` like brackets in C#, `{ ... }`, or something else entirely?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They come in a variety of flavors (try, catch) but generally they look like

```
BEGIN
    PRINT 'I am a block'
    RETURN
    PRINT 'I am still in a block but you will not see me'
END    
PRINT 'Too late, we returned from the above block'
```

Comment: So, the ONLY thing that prints from that sample is 'I am a block'?

Comment: @billinkc you seem to imply that the last line would print, but this is not true... `RETURN` will escape the scope outside of the `BEGIN`/`END` block as well.

Comment: I finally got to a computer I could test this with.  The only output from the code sample in the answer is 'I am a block'.  Thanks for the answer and the sample!

Comment: @John - [For future reference](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/qt/111168/)

Comment: @Martin Smith - Heh, nice! Duly noted!  +1

Comment: Edited original answer to make the above point clear to someone who doesn't stop to read the comment section, pending peer review.

Answer (score 2):

I would agree that that sentence in the documentation is misleading.

`RETURN` will not just exit the most immediate `BEGIN END` block (which can be nested), but will return from the entire function or procedure, and I'm not sure what it really means to exit a batch - perhaps in SSMS with the GO separator, it would continue to run later batches (I'll have to test that) - GO is a client side thing, so I'm not sure how useful that concept is in practice.

Comment: One example of a batch without `GO` would be an `EXEC ('dynamic sql statement')` but maybe that's not what you meant.

Comment: @Martin Smith I'd have to test `EXEC('stmt1;RETURN;stmt2;');`  I've never user return outside of a function or procedure.